# Eloquent. Usar dos where de una misma columna con valores diferentes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Quiero obtener todos los product_id que tengra el attribute_id 10 y el 17

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando la siguiente consulta pero no me funciona

```
$product_id = App\Attribute_Product::where('attribute_id', '10')
                            ->where('attribute_id', '17')->get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como explico antes en un comentario, creo que traes un fallo de concepto desde atrás.

Suponiendo que tienes la clase Product y Atributte ya creadas, vas a necesitar la relación con atributos.

```
public function atributos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Atributte::class);
}
```

Y al realizar la query, tendrás que concatenar los whereHas o whereExist para que sea obligatorio cumplir ambas relaciones. (Puedes hacerla dinámica con un for antes de ejecutar el get())

```
Product::select('id')
        ->wherehas('atributos', function ($q){
            $q->where('attribute_id', 10);
        })->wherehas('atributos', function ($q){
            $q->where('attribute_id', 17);
        })->get();
```

Si fuera como el caso que comentan el resto de compañeros, al tratarse de una tabla pivot, hay formas mas adecuadas de hacerlo tales como

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Atributte::class)->wherePivot('attribute_id', 10); // Solo para una
return $this->belongsToMany(Atributte::class)->whrePivotIn('attribute_id', [10, 17]); // Para mas de una posibilidad (OR)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono. Que dios te bendiga.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que al usar ->where->where, usas AND, y tu necesitas usar OR, de acuerdo a la documentacion debes usar orWhere, que te daria un script como el siguiente

```
Select * from Attribute_producte where attribute_id = 10 OR attribute_id = 17

$product_id = App\Attribute_Product::where('attribute_id', '10')
                        ->orWhere('attribute_id', '17')->get()
```

Ya que

```
Select * from Attribute_producte where attribute_id = 10 AND attribute_id = 17
```

Nunca va a ser cierto